# converting object to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I was trying to convert time object to datetime64 format. I used following:

`time =['87:38:00','51:48:00','26:05:00','10:04','69:21:00','66:56:00','47:12:00']
time1 =pd.to_datetime(time, format ='%d/%m/%Y/%H/%m/%s', errors ='coerce')`

it (time1) returned me object.
How can i convert it to datetime64[ns]
Thanks
zephyr

Comment: Don't use `errors='coerce'`. That is hiding valuable debugging information from you. Your format string is incorrect: `%m` stands for zero-padded month number, and you use it twice. `%m%s` should be `%M%S`. Also, none of the input strings match the format string. Reference: http://strftime.org/

Comment: Thanks Peter for the suggestion.
this is part of CSV file and how can i change the format of time in program?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)s - first convert list to `Series`, convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and remove last `:00` by condition with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and add `00:` for zero hours:

```
time =['87:38:00','51:48:00','26:05:00','10:04','69:21:00','66:56:00','47:12:00']
time = pd.Series(time)

m = time.str.count(':') == 2
time1 = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + time.mask(m, time.str.replace(':00$', '')))

print (time1)
0   01:27:38
1   00:51:48
2   00:26:05
3   00:10:04
4   01:09:21
5   01:06:56
6   00:47:12
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```