# How to handle irregular format from CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying different ways to handle date time in Pandas from CSV.

I have 3 columns in csv file:

1. **kickoffDate**
2. **kickoffTime**
3. **time**

The first two columns are well formatted. But the format of  third column "time" is mixed up.. some represents as time, some represent as date time.

For example:

```
12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 9:04:00 PM
```

How do I make same format using pandas?

Second thing is that I want to add all three columns to get a event time.

For example:

```
kickoffDate =['8/6/2017','8/6/2017','8/6/2017']
kickoffTime =['15:00:00','15:00:00','15:00:00']
time =['51:48:00','86:05:00','10:04']`
```

time in this case is `mm:ss:00` format. i want to combine those three column to create a new column so called `eventdatetime`:

```
eventdatetime = [06-08-2017 15:51:48, 06-08-2017 16:26:05,06-08-2017 15:10:04]`
```

How can i do this? I am able to combine the first two by using following formula:

```
DateTime1 = data['kickoffDate']+' '+ data ['kickoffTime']
```

The original csv file can be downloaded from below link:

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JL65x7nq2m6zk4qnaRUDKL894aEdXW_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter `parse_dates` with first and second columns for `datetimes`, then convert last column [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with adding `00:` for hours for values with no one `:`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Datetimetest.csv', parse_dates=[[0, 1]])

m = df['time'].str.count(':') != 1
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'].mask(m, df['time'].str.replace(':00$', '')))
df['eventdatetime'] = df['kickoffDate_kickoffTime'] + df['time']
print (df.head())
  kickoffDate_kickoffTime     time       eventdatetime
0     2018-04-30 19:00:00 00:47:36 2018-04-30 19:47:36
1     2018-04-30 19:00:00 00:15:28 2018-04-30 19:15:28
2     2018-04-29 13:15:00 00:52:03 2018-04-29 14:07:03
3     2018-04-29 13:15:00 01:03:42 2018-04-29 14:18:42
4     2018-04-29 13:15:00 00:10:43 2018-04-29 13:25:43
```

Another solution if want 4 separately columns in output - convert to datetimes only first column and another to `timedelta`s:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Datetimetest.csv', parse_dates=[0])

m = df['time'].str.count(':') != 1
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'].mask(m, df['time'].str.replace(':00$', '')))
df['kickoffTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['kickoffTime'])
df['eventdatetime'] = df['kickoffDate'] + df['kickoffTime'] + df['time']
print (df.head())
  kickoffDate kickoffTime     time       eventdatetime
0  2018-04-30    19:00:00 00:47:36 2018-04-30 19:47:36
1  2018-04-30    19:00:00 00:15:28 2018-04-30 19:15:28
2  2018-04-29    13:15:00 00:52:03 2018-04-29 14:07:03
3  2018-04-29    13:15:00 01:03:42 2018-04-29 14:18:42
4  2018-04-29    13:15:00 00:10:43 2018-04-29 13:25:43
```

EDIT:

If input data is not `csv`, for convert first column to datetime is possible use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead parameter `parse_dates` in `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Datetimetest.csv')

m = df['time'].str.count(':') != 1
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'].mask(m, df['time'].str.replace(':00$', '')))

df['kickoffDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['kickoffDate'])
df['kickoffTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['kickoffTime'])
df['eventdatetime'] = df['kickoffDate'] + df['kickoffTime'] + df['time']
print (df.head())
  kickoffDate kickoffTime     time       eventdatetime
0  2018-04-30    19:00:00 00:47:36 2018-04-30 19:47:36
1  2018-04-30    19:00:00 00:15:28 2018-04-30 19:15:28
2  2018-04-29    13:15:00 00:52:03 2018-04-29 14:07:03
3  2018-04-29    13:15:00 01:03:42 2018-04-29 14:18:42
4  2018-04-29    13:15:00 00:10:43 2018-04-29 13:25:43
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael,
the data from third columns is basically minutes and seconds.
If we look at the first row from your output.
the eventdatetime i expect is 2018-0-30 19:18:36
May I know how to deal with it?

Comment: @Zephyr - first row is `4/30/2018,19:00:00,47:36:00`, why need `2018-0-30 19:18:36` ? It is not `2018-04-30 19:47:36` ? Please check edited answer.

Comment: Oh Sorry,  my bad, it should be 2018-04-30 19:47:36

Comment: Hi Jez,
It works till 3rd line of the code.
when i add them together, i have got the error.


`eventdata['eventdatetime'] = eventdata['kickoffDate'] + eventdata['kickoffTime'] + eventdata['time']`

** ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')**
above error pops up.
Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr - It seems you forget `parse_dates` parameter.

Comment: got it sorted,Jez.
I add one line 



`eventdata['kickoffDate']= pd.to_datetime(eventdata.kickoffDate, format ='%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: @Zephyr - Super :) Can you accept also my previous answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50225050/2901002) ? Thank you.